# Dropdownlist Disable and Enable regarding Checkbox Action in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my MVC Application my form contains a checkbox and dropdownlist.When i check the checkbox to true i want to disable dropdownlist and vice versa. Also i want to populate a 'None' value as the selected item in dropdownlist, there is some other datas in dropdownlist populating from db. There have any solution? Please help me to resolve this.
Thanks

Comment: In my .cshtml file                                               <td style="width: 150px">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive)</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive)</td>
            <td style="width: 300px">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive)</td>

Comment: Go through some javascript/jquery tutorials that shows how to manipulate DOM

Comment: Is it possible without Jquery?And how can i set a default none value in the top of dropdownlistitems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use javascript for this. With jQuery you could subscribe to the `.change` event of the checkbox and toggle the dropdown's disabled attribute:

```
$(function() {
    $('#id_of_your_checkbox').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            // disable the dropdown:
            $('#id_of_dropdown').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#id_of_dropdown').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

> Also i want to populate a 'None' value as the selected item in dropdownlist

That's not a pretty common requirement. You will have to add this item manually in front of the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` collection that you are passing as second argument to the DropDownListFor helper.

Comment: Thanks Darin for your valuable answer.It save my lot of time..because i am new in mvc and jquery.............One thing i have noticed that the checkbox is selected when the form first loads.at that time we can select select from dropdown.how can i disable this @the form load?